# How to enable addressing feature in cxf xml?

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel, cxf, ws-addressing

How can I add default WS-addressing to the xml?

```xml
    <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="endpoint" xmlns:s="http://tempuri.org/"
      address="https://uslugaterytws1test.stat.gov.pl/TerytWs1.svc" 
      endpointName="s:custom" 
      serviceName="s:TerytWs1" 
      wsdlURL="classpath:/wsdl/terytws1.wsdl">
    <cxf:properties>
      <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="false" />
    </cxf:properties>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
    </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
    <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
    </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
  </cxf:cxfEndpoint>


  <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="poxyEndpoint" xmlns:s="http://tempuri.org/"
      address="http:localhost:5678/myproxy" 
      endpointName="s:customProxy" 
      serviceName="s:TerytWs1Proxy" 
      wsdlURL="classpath:/wsdl/terytws1Proxy.wsdl">
    <cxf:properties>
      <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="false" />
    </cxf:properties>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
    </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
      <ref component-id="wssOutInterceptor" />
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
    <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
      <ref component-id="wssOutInterceptor" />
    </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
  </cxf:cxfEndpoint>



  <camelContext id="proxyTerytContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
  <route id="route-TerytWs1">
      <from id="inbound" uri="cxf:bean:proxyEndpoint?dataFormat=CXF_MESSAGE" />
      <to id="outbound" uri="cxf:bean:endpoint?dataFormat=CXF_MESSAGE" />
    </route>
  </camelContext>
```

When I send request to `http:localhost:5678/myproxy` then I get:

```
<faultcode xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:InvalidSecurity</faultcode>
<faultstring xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred when verifying security for the message.</faultstring>
```

I have read many similar questions and examples but haven't found the solution for pure cxf xml. I have been trying to solve this for 2 days. Now I'm crying.

---

EDIT: 
This is an original wsdl: https://uslugaterytws1test.stat.gov.pl/terytws1.svc?wsdl
and this is my proxy to it: https://github.com/woblak/training/blob/master/teryt_testProxy.wsdl
user: TestPubliczny
pass: 1234abcd

Comment: Might be helpful if you post your WSDLs, how you're invoking your proxy service and how you're supplying the credentials.

Comment: I have added wsdls as ya said.

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples in the Camel unit tests which test CXF endpoints with WS-Addressing enabled; [WSAddressingTest-context.xml](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-3.2.0/components/camel-cxf/src/test/resources/org/apache/camel/component/cxf/wsa/WSAddressingTest-context.xml) seems like it might be relevant to your question?

Here, WS-Addressing has been enabled on a CXF endpoint by adding the `wsa:addressing` element in `features`:

```xml
<cxf:cxfEndpoint...>
    <cxf:features>
        <wsa:addressing xmlns:wsa="http://cxf.apache.org/ws/addressing" />
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

The error seems to be related to security. You have an interceptor configured (`wssOutInterceptor`) but there's no source code. Perhaps you should look there to see if you're setting the auth details.

I would also add [message logging](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/message-logging.html) so you can see the content of the payload sent to the target and verify that it contains your credentials.

Or, if you're using the Camel CXF namespace ( `xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"`) you can use:

```xml
<cxf:cxfEndpoint ... loggingFeatureEnabled="true">
  ...
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```